# Filter data-frame for rows dates outside a date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` where the head looks like:

```
    identifier        department    organisation    status change date
1           14           Finance        Accounts            19/09/2018
2           19         Marketing     Advertising            19/09/2016
22         288        Production              IT            03/01/2017
27         352        Facilities         Kitchen            31/01/2017
54         790         Relations           Sales            31/03/2017
```

`df` has several thousand records in it.  I also have 2 date variables - the start date and end date of a reference period as strings (arguments from the command line) called:

`referencePeriodStartDate` and `referencePeriodEndDate`

which currently equal:

```
referencePeriodStartDate = 01/01/2017
referencePeriodEndDate = 30/03/2017
```

I am trying to return and records from `df` which have a status change date that falls outside the reference period as setup by the `referencePeriodStartDate` and `referencePeriodEndDate`

In the example above records with identifier `14` and `19` would be returned as the status change dates they have `19/09/2018`  and `19/09/2016` are after and before the reference window respectively.

Example output

```
    identifier        department    organisation    status change date
1           14           Finance        Accounts            19/09/2018
2           19         Marketing     Advertising            19/09/2016
```

I have tried the following

```
resultdf = (df['status change date'].dt.date > referencePeriodEndDate.dt.date) & (df['status change date'].dt.date < referencePeriodStartDate.dt.date)
```

Where I convert the string dates to type date and try and apply the the logic if the status change date is smaller than `referencePeriodStartDate` and status change date > `referencePeriodEndDate` then return the row.

My problem is that nothing is returned.  Have I converted to type date incorrectly?

Comment: Row `54` was returned too. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If want compare dates from column created by [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with scalar date need [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

```
df['status change date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['status change date'])
referencePeriodStartDate =  pd.to_datetime('01/01/2017')
referencePeriodEndDate = pd.to_datetime('30/03/2017')

resultdf = df[(df['status change date'].dt.date > referencePeriodEndDate.date()) | 
              (df['status change date'].dt.date < referencePeriodStartDate.date())]
print (resultdf)
    identifier department organisation status change date
1           14    Finance     Accounts         2018-09-19
2           19  Marketing  Advertising         2016-09-19
54         790  Relations        Sales         2017-03-31
```

Or for compare datetimes only remove dates or use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) witn inverted condition by `~`:

```
df['status change date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['status change date'])
referencePeriodStartDate =  '01/01/2017'
referencePeriodEndDate =   '30/03/2017'

resultdf = df[(df['status change date'] > referencePeriodEndDate) |
              (df['status change date'] < referencePeriodStartDate)]
print (resultdf)
    identifier department organisation status change date
1           14    Finance     Accounts         2018-09-19
2           19  Marketing  Advertising         2016-09-19
54         790  Relations        Sales         2017-03-31
```

---

```
mask = ~df['status change date'].between(referencePeriodStartDate, referencePeriodEndDate)
resultdf = df[mask]
print (resultdf)
    identifier department organisation status change date
1           14    Finance     Accounts         2018-09-19
2           19  Marketing  Advertising         2016-09-19
54         790  Relations        Sales         2017-03-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the code from Jezrael mentions, you're slicing using '&'. Your dates cannot be after x '&' at the same time before 'y'. Convert the string to datetype and then use 'or' OR '|'